# Asterisk: sip phones can detect hangup from ptsn phone outside of asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

A little complex situation.
I have a little asterisk server,works fine but has
one problem: if someone answer from a ptsn phone outside
asterisk,the sip phones of asterisk still ringin and waiting.
And you can hear the voicemail answering(sic!).
My home has 4 fxo "ports" on one port i connect the asterisk and the analogic phone via Wildcard TDM400P card with two modules.
The other 3 ports has analogic phones connect,the problem is
:if someone call and some other answer from one of the 3 phones
outside of asterisk,the sip phones connected via lan still ringin.
The question is: is possible for asterisk to detect the answer outside?
Any parameter to check?Thanks

This is my context in extensions.conf
I see asterisk give me errror "exit non 0 state on s,3 extension"

```
[entrata]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,2,GotoIf(${BLACKLIST()}?blacklisted)
exten => s,3,Dial(SIP/1002&SIP/1001&dahdi/1,150,t,m,r)
;exten => s,3,Voicemail(1002@interni)
exten => s,4,Hangup()
```

This is the dadhi-channels.conf

```
;;; line="1 WCTDM/4/0"
signalling=fxo_ks
callerid="Centralino Asterisk"
mailbox=4001
group=0
context=interni
channel => 1
context=default

;;; line="4 WCTDM/4/3"
signalling=fxs_ks
callerid=asreceived
group=0
context=entrata
channel => 4
context=default
```

and chan_dadhi.conf

```
[channels]
context=entrata
language=it
signalling=fxs_ks
rxwink=300              ; Atlas seems to use long (250ms) winks
usecallerid=yes
hidecallerid=no
callwaiting=yes
usecallingpres=yes
callwaitingcallerid=yes
threewaycalling=yes
transfer=yes
canpark=yes
cancallforward=yes
callreturn=yes
echocancel=yes
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
faxdetect=incoming
echotraining=800
rxgain=0.0
txgain=0.0
callgroup=2
pickupgroup=2
immediate=no
;Uncomment these lines if you have problems with the disconection of your analog lines
busydetect=yes
busycount=6

#include /etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf
```

Comment: That is not asterisk question actually. You should check card settings(answer and hangup detect) in /etc/dahdi/system.conf and /etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf

Comment: thanks i will check and try

Comment: no way,tried a lot of combination of system.conf

Comment: This is a common FXO tone detection problem. Can you post your settings and Asterisk debug ? Please check your provider settings in FXO. The TDM400 is end of life.Please look at this:  http://serverfault.com/questions/144713/pstn-trunk-tdm400p-install-on-asterisk-trixbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common FXO tone detection problem. Please check your provider settings in FXO. The TDM400 is end of life.Please look at this:  https://serverfault.com/questions/144713/pstn-trunk-tdm400p-install-on-asterisk-trixbox

Comment: Looked and applied but...nothing to do